# Checkstyle - limit method exit points to five

Tags: checkstyle

We are allowing up to five return statements pro method. Is there a check rule that would give me a waring if method has more then five return statements?

ps. please do not start discussion on "why would I allow more then one exit point" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is the [ReturnCount](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#ReturnCount) check. Configure like this:

```xml
<module name="ReturnCount">
    <property name="max" value="5"/>
</module>
```

You can also give it the names of methods that are ignored by the check (see linked docs).